# Image display, saved in SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am trying to display an image which I saved in my SQL Server database.

This is the code I am using.

```
public partial class SavedFileDisplay : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string strQuery = "select Name, ContentType, Data from tblFiles where id = @id";

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["ImageID"]);

        DataTable dt = GetData(cmd);

        if (dt != null)
        {
             Byte[] bytes = (Byte[])dt.Rows[0]["Data"];
             Response.Buffer = true;
             Response.Charset = "";
             Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
             Response.ContentType = dt.Rows[0]["ContentType"].ToString();
             Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + dt.Rows[0]["Name"].ToString());
             Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
             Response.Flush();
             Response.End();
         }
    }

    private Boolean GetData(SqlCommand cmd)
    {
         String strConnString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager
    .ConnectionStrings["conString"].ConnectionString;

         SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
         cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
         cmd.Connection = con;

         try
         {
              con.Open();
              cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
              return true;
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
              Response.Write(ex.Message);
             return false;
         }
         finally
         {
              con.Close();
              con.Dispose();
         }
    }
}
```

The problem is, the function `GetData` is saving data in a datatable but the function is of type `boolean`. Please help me in writing correct code for this.

Comment: Where is `cmd.CommandText = "Select * from ....`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assigning a bool value to a DataTable (`DataTable dt = GetData(cmd);`), since `GetData()` returns bool, which cannot work. You need to change the return value of GetData to a DataTable and change the logic of GetData to retrieve the data from your database and push it into a datatable:

```
private DataTable GetData(SqlCommand cmd)
{
    String strConnString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conString"].ConnectionString;
    using(var con = new SqlConnection(strConnString))
    {
         cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
         cmd.Connection = con;
         con.Open();

         DataTable dt = new DataTable();
         //load data into datatable here
         dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
         return dt;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you need a method that returns a `DataTable` instead of `bool`

```
private DataTable GetData(SqlCommand cmd)
{
    string myConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conString"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection myConn = new SqlConnection(myConnectionString))
    {
        cmd.Connection = myConn;
        using (SqlDataAdapter myDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
        {

            DataTable dtResult = new DataTable();
            myDataAdapter.Fill(dtResult);
            return dtResult;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @ fubo : dear i used your given code but is showing error ( using (SqlDataAdapter myDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd, myConnection)))
saying that there is some invalid arguments. please help.

Comment: @Mr.Waqas - you're right, i updated my answer - anyway i would put `SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery)` into a using directive too